# How to add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library and Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 using macro code

Tags: vba, excel

I always added references into my .bas module through "Tools...->References...". And now I want to add references automatically, using macro code. I need to add the two references: `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` and `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`. And I found a piece of code that seems to do what I want:

```
Sub ListReferences()
    On Error GoTo CanNotAddReferences
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "PATH_TO_FILE"
    Exit Sub
CanNotAddReferences:
    MsgBox "Can not add reference"
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to get paths of files (`PATH_TO_FILE`). Maybe somebody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are system .dll files, but why do you need to add them? If you set a reference in a project it transfers with that project so you shouldn't really need to do this. The other issue is that unless the other user has enabled programmatic access to the VBP Object Model this code will always fail - I would use late binding instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the file path on the *References VBAProject* dialog (Tools >> References).  Look for the location property.

[image: References VBAProject Dialog]

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, you cannot always read the full name.  This sub outputs all the current references.

```
Sub ReadExistingRefences()
' Displays all current refernce names and full paths.
Dim ref As Object

    For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
        MsgBox "Name: " & ref.Name & vbCrLf & ref.FullPath
    Next
End Sub
```

**Warning**

You should really read @MacroMan's comment on the OP.  Although you *can* update references programmatically, you probably *shouldn't*.

Comment: I can't read the full path (in long paths), like the example in this answer, is there any way to read or copy it?.

Comment: Yes.  Add a reference manually then check the Name and FullPath properties of the Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References(x) object.  Replace (x) with (1), (2), etc until you find the correct reference.  As before; I would recommend you read @MarcoMan's comment first.  You shouldn't need to do this.  It is harder to solve problems using this method than late binding.

Comment: @destination-data, thank you `Debug.Print Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References(4).FullPath`